# Converting dates SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

Can anyone stop me going crazy here. I have the following dataset, and I can't use covert. I need them all in a datetime format.

You can see what I've tried in the commented code, but I'm seriously lost with this one.

`SALESDATE` is `mm/dd/yyyy` and `EVENTDATE` is the same.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyaGB.jpg

[image: My attempt]

Comment: Those dates look like you should be using style 101 (m/d/y), not 103 (d/m/y).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - those dates make me worry, a lot. All of the ones which are unambiguously `m/d/y` are formatted differently from the ambiguous ones - I've seen such issues in the past where it turns out the ambiguous ones have been stored `d/m/y` and the unambiguous ones `m/d/y`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it worries me too... unfortunately it's client data.

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is to find out what those dates (where they're ambiguous) are actually meant to represent. If the client can't answer that, you may as well give them back `NULL`s.

Comment: It makes me curious to know the datatype of those fields, and is there any index on those fields. Also the version of the server. 
And please share, if you are able to findout the reason of this ambiguous data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
select 
   convert(varchar(30), convert(datetime, salesdate), 101) 
from [OLE DB DESTINATION03]
```

Comment: Oh man you're so close it pains me... Select top 100 is giving the correct results, but it's falling over somewhere in the middle on a random date. I'll have to manually check through and see what's up. I'll upvote your answer for now but can't mark as correct for now.